# how do i use for loop for correct options i gave under print command?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, nested-for-loop

i know how to use for loop and if statement separately but when using together i am stuck on this problem.

```py
print(''' a. mumbai
\n b.delhi
\n c. chennai''')
city=(input('enter your city:'))
for options in city:
    print('choose you budget:')
    print('''a.2k
    \n b. 5k
    \n c. 8k''')
else:
   print('no hotels found')
```

i wanted that when i enter one of the options i gave under 'city', it gives me the 'budget' and when i enter something else it prints ' no hotels found' and gives the option to enter the city again until it satisfies one from the given options but instead when i enter anything it shows me the budget and later shows'no hotels found'.
is the for cannot be used for something written inside print or am doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this logic flow for what you want to achieve:

1. Display City Options
2. Get the user’s City Options Input
3. Display the Budget Options
4. Get the user’s Budget Options Input
5. Check if there are any offerings in the selected city (matching the value retrieved from Step 2) and budget option value (matching the value retrieved from Step 4)
6. Display any results from the matches of step 5 or display a message stating that no matches were found.

From my understanding you’re missing Step 4… you’re skipping the retrieval of the user’s budget option input.

You’re missing the if statement (in step 5) hence it’s executing the code found in the else statement.
You need to write the code with searches for the chosen city and budget match… you can use a boolean to retrieve the result of this match… and then write an if statement based on the boolean value to display the hotels which are in the chosen city and offer bookings matching the chosen budget… followed by an else statement displaying the “No hotels found”.
Here’s a fix to your code which was posted in your original post:

```
print(''' a. mumbai
\n b.delhi
\n c. chennai''')
city=(input('enter your city:'))
for options in city:
print('choose you budget:')
print('''a.2k
\n b. 5k
\n c. 8k''')
budget=(input(‘choose you budget:’)
!! Write code to search matches based
to search for input matches !!
if (boolean match == true)
foreach (resultmatch in resultmatches){
print resultmatch}

else:
print('no hotels found')
```

You need to write the result matches and if statement code… I included some pseudo code within !! !!

Comment: hey, am sorry i missed a point in my question. i'll be happy if you could re-read my question and answer it again accordingly.

Comment: Do you want it to look for a match based on the user’s chosen city & budget and display the results… if not “no hotels found” message is returned?

Comment: you're correct for the first part but if the user choses something else other than the options provided then again the options should appear and the system asks for the input again until the user choses one from the option like a loop.